# aiogram отправка сообщения в отдельном потоке

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram, multiprocessing

Есть такой вот код, который запускает бота и отдельный поток с функцией.

```
import time
from classes.Bot import dp, on_startup, on_shutdown
from aiogram import executor
from multiprocessing import Process
import schedule
from functions.send_all_archives_function import send_all_archives_function


def start_schedule():
    schedule.every().tuesday.at("08:00").do(send_all_archives_function)
    while True:
        schedule.run_pending()
        time.sleep(1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Process(target=start_schedule, args=()).start()
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=False, on_startup=on_startup, on_shutdown=on_shutdown)
```

А вот функция, которую код запускает по вторникам в 8 утра

```
import os
from loguru import logger
from classes.Stepik import Stepik, gel_all_users


def send_all_archives_function():
    for i in gel_all_users():
        stepik = Stepik(i["telegram_id"])
        stepik.start()
        try:
            await message.reply_document(open('zip.zip', 'rb'))
            os.remove("zip.zip")
        except FileNotFoundError:
            await message.reply("У вас нет курсов")
    logger.info(f"отправка всех сообщений закончена")
```

И тут мне нужно чтобы бот отправлял архивы в сообщении людям, но как я понял telegram api не разрешит мне создать 2 подключения, поэтому я в недоумении, как же мне отправлять сообщения в другом потоке. Заранее спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я себе сделал через APScheduler. Через него точно сработает. Во всяком случае я отправляю сообщения в других потоках.

См. пример:
https://telegra.ph/Zapusk-funkcij-v-bote-po-tajmeru-11-28

Документация: https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/stable/userguide.html